# iOS7 - Outputting frames with AVCaptureMetadataOutput?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation

I am trying to use the iOS7 QR reading functions in the `AVFoundation` framework using the following code:

```
-(void)setupCaptureSession_iOS7 {
    self.session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSError *error = nil;

    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device
                                                                        error:&error];
    if (!input)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    [session addInput:input];

    //Turn on point autofocus for middle of view
    [device lockForConfiguration:&error];
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);
    [device setFocusPointOfInterest:point];
    [device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus];
    [device unlockForConfiguration];

    //Add the metadata output device
    AVCaptureMetadataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
    [output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [session addOutput:output];

    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)output.availableMetadataObjectTypes.count);
    for (NSString *s in output.availableMetadataObjectTypes)
        NSLog(@"%@",s);

    //You should check here to see if the session supports these types, if they aren't support you'll get an exception
    output.metadataObjectTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode];
    output.rectOfInterest = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

    [session startRunning];

    // Assign session to an ivar.
    [self setSession:self.session];

}
```

This code obviously doesn't render the frames to the screen (yet). This is because, instead of using the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` class to display the preview, I need to display the frames as a `UIImage` (this is because I have want to display the frames multiple times on the view).

If I use `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` as the output, I'm able to export the frames using by grabbing them from the `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:` callback. But I can't find an equivalent way to call get the frameBuffer when using `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` as the output.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?